# Why can't Django 2.0.1 be found when running Circle CI?

Tags: python, django, circleci

I'm running Circle CI on a Django project. The build fails, and the results show that Django 2.0.1 couldn't be installed. **Why is the build failing?**

I was previously using Gitlab CI without any problems. The installation runs from my requirements.txt which contains `Django==2.0.1`.

**config.yml**

```
# Python CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-python/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      # use `-browsers` prefix for selenium tests, e.g. `3.6.1-browsers`
      # - image: circleci/python:3.6.1
      - image: python:latest

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ./venv
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}

      # run tests!
      # this example uses Django's built-in test-runner
      # other common Python testing frameworks include pytest and nose
      # https://pytest.org
      # https://nose.readthedocs.io
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports
          destination: test-reports
```

Here's the log from where CI is breaking:

```
...
Collecting Django==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10)
No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))

if [ -e requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt;else pip install -r requirements.pip;fi returned exit code 1

Action failed: pip install
```

Comment: You are building on python 2 and django > 2.0 only supports python 3.

Comment: Actually, I see that you are specifying `python3` when creating the venv, but not running `pip`. I am not sure how it doesn't bail there since `python:latest` shouldn't even contain python3.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Python 3 Docker image (not 2), and I wouldn't use venv here considering the CI use case and that PipEnv now exists. Here's an example CircleCI 2.0 config from our Django example project: https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-python-django/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI